# JQuery Not working properly

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to accomplish swap images with text using the `.html()` function in JQuery. I am having some issues.

**FIRST**:

If the mouse moves around too fast, the function is delayed and does not work. The onHover even seems to get stuck on the mouse over and onmouse out does not fire.

HTML:

```
<table border=0 cellPadding=2 cellSpacing=5 width=100% class=showlangs>
    <tr>
        <td id="arabic">
            <img src="theImages/languages/arabic.png" />
        </td>
        <td id="khmer">
            <img src="theImages/languages/khmer.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="armenian">
            <img src="theImages/languages/armenian.png" />
        </td>
        <td id="korean">
            <img src="theImages/languages/korean.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="bengali">
            <img src="theImages/languages/bengali.png" />
        </td>
        <td id="laotian">
            <img src="theImages/languages/laotian.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cantonese">
            <img src="theImages/languages/cantonese.png" />
        </td>
        <td id="mandarin">
            <img src="theImages/languages/mandarin.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="english">
            <img src="theImages/languages/english.png" />
        </td>
        <td id="polish">
            <img src="theImages/languages/polish.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="french">
            <img src="theImages/languages/french.png" />
        </td>
        <td id="portugese">
            <img src="theImages/languages/portugese.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="german">
            <img src="theImages/languages/german.png" />
        </td>
        <td id="russian">
            <img src="theImages/languages/russian.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="hindi">
            <img src="theImages/languages/hindi.png" />
        </td>
        <td id="spanish">
            <img src="theImages/languages/spanish.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="hmong">
            <img src="theImages/languages/hmong.png" />
        </td>
        <td id="tagalog">
            <img src="theImages/languages/tagalog.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="italian">
            <img src="theImages/languages/italian.png" />
        </td>
        <td id="thai">
            <img src="theImages/languages/thai.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="japanese">
            <img src="theImages/languages/japanese.png" />
        </td>
        <td id="vietnamese">
            <img src="theImages/languages/vietnamese.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#arabic").hover(function(){
        $("#arabic").html('<b class="langs">ARABIC</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#arabic").html('<img src="theImages/languages/arabic.png" />');
    });
    $("#armenian").hover(function(){
        $("#armenian").html('<b class="langs">ARMENIAN</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#armenian").html('<img src="theImages/languages/armenian.png" />');
    });
    $("#bengali").hover(function(){
        $("#bengali").html('<b class="langs">BENGALI</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#bengali").html('<img src="theImages/languages/bengali.png" />');
    });
    $("#cantonese").hover(function(){
        $("#cantonese").html('<b class="langs">CANTONESE</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#cantonese").html('<img src="theImages/languages/cantonese.png" />');
    });
    $("#english").hover(function(){
        $("#english").html('<b class="langs">ENGLISH</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#english").html('<img src="theImages/languages/english.png" />');
    });
    $("#french").hover(function(){
        $("#french").html('<b class="langs">FRENCH</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#french").html('<img src="theImages/languages/french.png" />');
    });
    $("#german").hover(function(){
        $("#german").html('<b class="langs">GERMAN</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#german").html('<img src="theImages/languages/german.png" />');
    });
    $("#hindi").hover(function(){
        $("#hindi").html('<b class="langs">HINDI</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#hindi").html('<img src="theImages/languages/hindi.png" />');
    });
    $("#hmong").hover(function(){
        $("#hmong").html('<b class="langs">HMONG</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#hmong").html('<img src="theImages/languages/hmong.png" />');
    });
    $("#italian").hover(function(){
        $("#italian").html('<b class="langs">ITALIAN</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#italian").html('<img src="theImages/languages/italian.png" />');
    });
    $("#japanese").hover(function(){
        $("#japanese").html('<b class="langs">JAPANESE</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#japanese").html('<img src="theImages/languages/japanese.png" />');
    });
    $("#khmer").hover(function(){
        $("#khmer").html('<b class="langs">KHMER</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#khmer").html('<img src="theImages/languages/khmer.png" />');
    });
    $("#korean").hover(function(){
        $("#korean").html('<b class="langs">KOREAN</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#korean").html('<img src="theImages/languages/korean.png" />');
    });
    $("#laotian").hover(function(){
        $("#laotian").html('<b class="langs">LAOTIAN</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#laotian").html('<img src="theImages/languages/laotian.png" />');
    });
    $("#mandarin").hover(function(){
        $("#mandarin").html('<b class="langs">MANDARIN</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#mandarin").html('<img src="theImages/languages/mandarin.png" />');
    });
    $("#polish").hover(function(){
        $("#polish").html('<b class="langs">POLISH</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#polish").html('<img src="theImages/languages/polish.png" />');
    });
    $("#portugese").hover(function(){
        $("#portugese").html('<b class="langs">PORTUGESE</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#portugese").html('<img src="theImages/languages/portugese.png" />');
    });
    $("#russian").hover(function(){
        $("#russian").html('<b class="langs">RUSSIAN</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#russian").html('<img src="theImages/languages/russian.png" />');
    });
    $("#spanish").hover(function(){
        $("#spanish").html('<b class="langs">SPANISH</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#spanish").html('<img src="theImages/languages/spanish.png" />');
    });
    $("#tagalog").hover(function(){
        $("#tagalog").html('<b class="langs">TAGALOG</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#tagalog").html('<img src="theImages/languages/tagalog.png" />');
    });
    $("#thai").hover(function(){
        $("#thai").html('<b class="langs">THAI</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#thai").html('<img src="theImages/languages/thai.png" />');
    });
    $("#vietnamese").hover(function(){
        $("#vietnamese").html('<b class="langs">VIETNAMESE</b>');
        },function(){
        $("#vietnamese").html('<img src="theImages/languages/vietnamese.png" />');
    });
});
```

So what is suppose to happen is, for example:
If I hover my mouse over the arabic image, it should replace the image with the "ARABIC" text and if I move the mouse out, it should replace the text with the image. But if I move the mouse too fast around all the TD some onmouseout does not fire.
Also can I have the fade in/out effect with the onmouseover and onmouseout event? (makes it more fancy)

**SECOND**:
I know there is a way to shorten the JQuery code above so it doesn't take up so many lines because it's doing the same thing for all the TD. How would I shorten the code, if possible?

Comment: When you add the new image, it has to load before it can be displayed. That's where your delay is. To solve it, use an image sprite, or preload the images.

Comment: You could refactorize your code to less than 10 lines using a css class instead of all these ids

Comment: When the page loads, all the images are already loaded, no?

Comment: @roasted, how would the 10 lines look like :)

Comment: hovering over the TD works fine, but the texts get stuck if the mouse is hovered over the images fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also store the language name in the alt text of the image (and thus be ADA compliant). You could then use a class selector for your `td` elements and swap out the alt text with the image. This has the benefit of still being kind to screen readers.

**EDIT** Because you are having issues with mouse movement speed, I would recommend against using `.fadeIn` and `.fadeOut` see alternate javascript below.

So, something akin to the following [(and Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/XGundam05/HRrHG/):

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.showlangs td', function(event){
    var _img = $(this).find('img');
    var _lang = $(_img).prop('alt');
    $(this).append('<span class="hidden"><strong>' + _lang + '</strong></span>');
    var _txt = $(this).find('span');
    $(_img).fadeOut();
    $(_txt).fadeIn();
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.showlangs td', function(event){
    $(this).find('img').fadeIn();
    $(this).find('span').fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

**Alternate Javascript/jQuery**

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.showlangs td', function(event){
    var _img = $(this).find('img');
    $(_img).hide();
    $(this).append('<b>' + $(_img).prop('alt') + '</b>');
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.showlangs td', function(event){
    $(this).find('b').remove();
    $(this).find('img').show();
});
```

**EDIT:** Cleaned up answer to shorten wall of code and use the asker's document selectors.

Comment: Can you please tell me why this happens, if I move the mouse around the images really fast the replacement image never kicks in (link: http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/au_language.php)

Comment: It's due in part because you're actually removing the `img` tag. It also appears to be due in part to the way that `hover` is triggered. When you move your mouse fast enough, the `hover` event isn't triggered. Messed with the JS on your site in chrome's console, and got it working fine using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

Comment: I suspected that. Thanks!
How would i take what "undefined" coded above to have mouseenter and mouseleave event?

Comment: Split it into 2 parts, `mouseenter` having the removal of the image and inserting of text and `mouseleave` having the removal of the text and insertion of the image. Considering the context of your site, you really should be using the `alt` tags on the images. Regardless of whether or not you use them for the javascript.

Comment: so the Alternate JS will cover the replacement of HOVER event? And I should be using ALT and TITLE for all my images. Thanks

Comment: Yep, the Alternate JS should work for you with modfications to the selector to fit your site.

Comment: The selector `.lang` needs changed to `.showlangs td` to work with your site setup.

Comment: I updated it but it's doing something totally weird... Nevermind, i edited your alternate jscript code to make it work correctly. THANKS :) (it's '.showlangs td' to work correctly)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('table.showlangs td').hover(function() {
     this.innerHTML = '<b class="langs">'+ this.id.toUpperCase() +'</b>';
 , function() {
     this.innerHTML = '<img src="theImages/languages/'+ this.id +'.png"/>';
});
```

Using `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods:

```
$('table.showlangs td').hover(function() {
     var $this = $(this),
         content = $this.children('b').length
                   ? '<img src="theImages/languages/'+ this.id +'.png"/>'
                   : '<b class="langs">'+ this.id.toUpperCase() +'</b>';
     $this.fadeOut('fast', function() {
         $this.html(content).fadeIn('fast');
     })   
});
```

Comment: I made some edit to your code, which works perfectly by the way :)

Comment: Would it be possible to include FADE() during the transition within the code?

Comment: The fading is very choppy in IE8 so i reverted back to the original code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would forego using JavaScript in place of CSS transitions as the browser will handle these on its own better than you ever could with JS.  This won't really work if you need to support the transitions with IE9-, but the showing/hiding will still work.

```
td strong, td img {
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
strong {
    opacity: 0;
}
td:hover img {
    opacity: 0;
}
td:hover strong {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sgjqZ/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can give Id to your table like

```
<table id="myTable" border=0 cellPadding=2 cellSpacing=5 width=100% class=showlangs> ...
```

Then you can use that Id to hook events

```
$("td", "#myTable").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("img").hide();
    $(this).find("b").show();
}, function () {
    $(this).find("img").show();
    $(this).find("b").hide();
});
```

The .html() changes the DOM and loads new image which may take time, instead you should include the object but hide/show it

```
<tr>
    <td id="arabic">
        <img src="theImages/languages/arabic.png" />
        <b class="langs" style="display: none;">ARABIC</b>
    </td>
    ...
</tr>
```